# What are these two forms of watch called?

Tags: image-identification

Nowadays in smartphones, computers or even in smart watches there are two types / form of watch display: one with clock hands and the second is simply three or four numbers (for example: 19:12). Can I call them simply as "clock hand form" or "digital numbers form"?  I tried to find out something about my question in a dictionary (using "clock hands") but I really didn't find. What are these two form of display called?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They are called "[analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock#Analog)" and "[digital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock#Digital)" clocks, respectively.

[Analog](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/analog) is a general term that means "of or relating to a mechanism that represents data by measurement of a continuous physical variable." So you can use it to describe any measuring device that uses some physical movement to make a measurement: a mercury thermometer or a car speedometer with a moving needle are "analog" devices, as is a clock with hands that move.